# Average and count with aggregation in R with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to count the number of elements for the variable price equal to 0, 49 or if something else I also want the count but i don't care how many the price is in this case.
I want to do an average of price by terminal if this one is not equal to 0 or 49

```
terminal <- c("a", "b", "a", "c", "b", "b")
price <- c(0, 49, 3.5, 0, 17, 32)
df <- data.frame(terminal, price)

df %>%
group_by(terminal, price) %>%
summarise(count = n())
```

Here I want to have this count : 1, 1, 2, 1, 1 
and after this I'd like to get an average of the price of terminal when this one is not equal to zero or 49.

Comment: Perhaps `df %>% group_by(terminal, gr= 1+2*(price==0)+4*(price==49)) %>% mutate(n=n()) %>% summarise(n=n[1], Avg = mean(price[!(price %in% c(0,49))], na.rm=TRUE))`

Comment: Can you show the expected output for the average of price

Comment: This is exactly what I want thank you very much, can you just explain me this line pls **gr= 1+2*(price==0)+4*(price==49)**
Impressive thanks again

Comment: I added some description to the solution posted below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to create a grouping variable with 'price' based on the values '0'  and '49'.  For this, one way would be to use `==` to get a logical index with both 0 and 49, do some arithmetic to so that we will be having 3 groups one for 0, one for 49, and the rest for all others.  Grouped by 'terminal' and 'gr', we `summarise` to get the number of rows i.e. 'n' and the `mean` of 'price' that are not 0, or 49 (using `%in%` and the negation `!`)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(terminal, gr= 1+2*(price==0)+4*(price==49)) %>% 
    summarise(n=n(), 
              Avg = mean(price[!(price %in% c(0,49))], na.rm=TRUE))
```