# Identify the frequency count behind an aggregate in r

Tags: r

Hello and good evening overflowers, this could very well be a super simple answer and I hope so, here goes nothing (apologies in advance if I am not supplying enough info).....
Long story short, I am trying to figure out the mean time to resolve a case per group and how many cases they have resolved. To identify the "MTTR" I do this :

```
avgMttrFreq <- aggregate(db$CAL_MTTR_CALC2 ~ db$ASSIGNMENT_GROUP, db ,mean)
avgMttrFreq[order(-avgMttrFreq[,2]),]
avgMttrOrder <-avgMttrFreq[order(-avgMttrFreq[,2]),]
avgMttrOrderDf <- data.frame(avgMttrOrder)
avgMttrTopX <- avgMttrOrderDf[1:20,]
avgMttrTopX
```

The output looks like this: 
[image]

Cool... now we can see the avg.mttr or mean time to resolve per group (sorted which is important), but I need to be able to **add** the "frequency" column..... what I mean is, how many observations are behind the 3k hrs to resolve in row one? any ideas on how we can do this?

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36183601/average-and-count-with-aggregation-in-r-with-dplyr) how to do it with dplyr.  I've provided a data.table approach below.  If you wanted to stick to Base R, you could do another `aggregate` call but with `length` instead of `mean` and then merge the two results from the `aggregate` calls together.  I know that's not elegant.  Maybe someone else can offer a better Base R approach.

Comment: i do not want to use the dplyr lib because it conflicts with other "count" functions that i am doing with the plyr lib. :( i just need to know how many observations are driving the mean (if that makes sense) and display them in a new column.

Comment: OK - see my edited answer below.  It's not great, but it keeps you in Base R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data.table way:

```
# example data
library(data.table)
data.table(
    group = sample(letters[1:3], 20, TRUE),
    time  = runif(20, 0, 10)
)

# or if your data are in a dataframe named 'df' convert to dt by:
dt <- as.data.table(df) #or just setDT(df)

# aggregate, creating 2 variables: avg_time and count
res <- dt[ , .(avg_time = mean(time), count = .N), by=group]

# print sorted result
res[order(avg_time, decreasing=TRUE)]
```

---

Inelegant Base R way:

```
# do mean and count (with length) separately
avgMttrFreq1 <- aggregate(CAL_MTTR_CALC2 ~ ASSIGNMENT_GROUP, db ,mean)
avgMttrFreq2 <- aggregate(CAL_MTTR_CALC2 ~ ASSIGNMENT_GROUP, db ,length)

# merge them together
avgMttrFreq <- merge(avgMttrFreq1, avgMttrFreq2, by="ASSIGNMENT_GROUP")

#then the rest of your code
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, but when running this, i get the following error:
Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column

Comment: Can you edit your question to include some of your data?  This is easy to do with `dput(head(your_df))`.  I'll have a better shot at getting the coding right if I actually have something to work with.

Comment: sorry, I was an idiot, your suggestion worked perfectly, I just used it incorrectly.. Last question, how do I sort via freq column? sort=T?.. for example, I have the following columns:
ASSIGNMENT_GROUP | CAL_MTTR_CALC2.x  | CAL_MTTR_CALC2.y
i want to know how to sort on column CAL_MTTR_CALC2.y or column: CAL_MTTR_CALC2.x

Comment: `df[order(df$col, decreasing=TRUE), ]`

Comment: Brilliant! thank you so much for the help Dan Y! ++ 100 karma points!

Comment: now, last and final question, can i subset what you just showed me by the "top 20" X?....
i want to do something like - avgMttrFreq[1:20,]

Comment: You have it right.  After sorting, do `df[1:20, ]`.  Or do it all in one shot: `df[order(df$col, decreasing=TRUE)[1:20], ]`

Comment: Dan, I know this is "silly", but thank you so much for the assistance here! you have helped me out so much, you have no idea!

Comment: Happy to help.  +15 rep and +100 karma :)

Comment: sorry to keep on bothering you Dan, super last question: how do i round the hours in this line?:
avgMttrFreq[order(avgMttrFreq$CAL_MTTR_CALC2.y, decreasing=T)[1:20], ]

Comment: Do the rounding separately first with `df$col <- round(df$col)`

Comment: Great idea, I tried that already, but for some reason the following line is not working:
db$CAL_MTTR_CALC2 <- round(db$CAL_MTTR_CALC2,1)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this one helps

```
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(db)
data[, list(count=length(CAL_MTTR_CALC2), mean=mean(CAL_MTTR_CALC2)), by=c("ASSIGNMENT_GROUP")]
```

Comment: thank you for the comment, but Dan (above) nailed it!